# Links in navbar with Rails and Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Say I have a `navbar`:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li><%= link_to 'Item 1', item1_path %>
  <li><%= link_to 'Item 2', item2_path %>
  ...
```

But this way current menu item is also a link. How do I make it into a `span`, preserving appearance? Which doesn't look like a good options, since in this case I need to duplicate `bootstrap`'s styles. Or make it look like a menu item without it pointing to any page?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap? I think bootstrap's way is to add a `active` class to current link.

Comment: To current **link**. That's the point. Current menu item is not supposed to be a link.

Comment: Why on earth wouldn't you use `link_to_unless_current`?

Comment: Then I'd need to duplicate menu item name. Which is not so bad. But why on earth can't I use a helper as in my answer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I came up with the following helper:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def menu_item(name, path)
    if current_page? path
      content_tag('a', name)
    else
      link_to name, path
    end
  end
end
```

With that we've just got to replace `link_to` with `menu_item` in original code.

Answer (score 0):

A link_to method will always render an `<a>` tag, but you can render a `<span>` *inside* of the `<a>` tag if you use `link_to ... do`

This is an example taken from [this](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to) documentation

```
<%= link_to(@profile) do %>
  <strong><%= @profile.name %></strong> -- <span>Check it out!</span>
<% end %>
<!-- which renders -->
<a href="/profiles/1">
       <strong>David</strong> -- <span>Check it out!</span>
</a>
```

Comment: I don't need just `span`.  I either need `span` with styling preserved. In which case I need to duplicate `bootstrap`'s styles. As such I don't consider it being a good option. Or any other way to make current menu item look like a menu item, but not point to any page. Like in my answer. In any case, you'd better off using `link_to_unless_current`.

Comment: @x-yuri you could also style the new span element you create, to create that first effect

Comment: Which would make me duplicate Bootstrap styles. Which I was talking about in the previous comment. Which I would like to avoid.